# Make bootstrap table row clickable in the most effective way

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I want to make a row become clickable along the way:

1. Most effective (server and client wise)
2. Make as many different browsers as possible with no adjustments on my part

I have the option to realize it in jquery like this:

```
// my tr (row) class
<tr class='clickable-row' data-href='url:www.google.com'>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#dtBasicExample").on('click', 'tbody > tr.clickable-row', function (e, row, $element) {
            window.location.href = $(this).data("href");
        });
    });
```

And I have the option to implement it in pure JS like this:

```
<tr onclick="document.location = '#';">
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
```

Which is more correct and which is better?

Comment: jquery is also just js, so both are equally correct.

Comment: @cloned so they both the same efficiency,performance and compatibility wise?

Comment: *"which is more correct / better"* in a coding context is generally subjective.  A jquery developer will tell you to use jquery as it's "better" (historically, substantially better for your requirement of browser compatibility, less so now, but also you may consider succinct as "better").

Comment: Generally, these days, it's considered better to keep form and function separate (not `<form>`...).  ie keep the html separate from any actions - ie don't use `onclick=`.  Whether you wire up that click with jquery or javascript is neither here nor there.

Comment: Performance differences on a single user interaction will almost always be negligible that it's not even worth consideration.  If you're running some js code on 10,000 links, then might be worth thinking about it (or thinking about why you would do that...)

Comment: If you're using doc ready to wire up a click handler, it's unlikely you'd need to worry about efficiency.  Of course, if that's *all* you're doing then you're also loading+parsing jquery itself, which won't be worth it for such a small use. But then, modern browsers also cache post-parsed javascript, so would, again, be negligible *after the first load*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BS class "stretched-link" (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/stretched-link/)

like so:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card with stretched link</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary stretched-link">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried on a table and worked just fine @ArsenIbragimov

Comment: Works also with Bootstrap 5.2 (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/helpers/stretched-link/). Just be sure to add the class `position-relative` to the containing `<tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Both are outputting the same result, since jQuery just adds the javascript code to the site once it's loaded. So there is no "better" way out of the two, it's personal preference.

As to which supports more browsers I tend to the pure JS solution, since this is a basic function that is even supported in IE6 still: [onClick Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick)

jQuery isn't necessarily supported in all browsers

Comment: What about efficiency?

Comment: both solutions create pure javascript code in the end which is executed on client-side, so both are equally efficient. Maybe the page_load is faster on the pure JS solution, because jQuery doen't need go through the DOM Tree and add the event to the element once the DOM is loaded. But I don't think this difference is measurable and can be disregarded